# Email Template in Java Getting disturbed after second mail onwards

Tags: java, jsp, email, freemarker

Mugging up for days, But couldn't find a way to sort it out.

Implementing to send mails in java using HTML and JSP view technologies.

Everything is fine if I am sending any mail to any email id only once by hard-coding some link (On all devices as ipad, iphone, windows etc.)

But while sending same mail by keeping that link dynamic, first mail is ok on all devices, but if I am sending same mail to same email id again(this issue is with gmail id only) entire formatting(Alignment is changerd from center to left) is getting disturbed for iphone and ipad(But it is ok for desktops, laptops).

Below is code I am using:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">"
+"\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">"
+"\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />"
+"\n<title>Share Deal</title>\n</head>"

+"<table width=\"560\" border=\"0\" align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#f4f2f3\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"> " +
"<tr>\n    <td height=\"70\" "
+ "align=\"center\"><a href=\""
+ logoLink
+ "\"><img alt='MNS Logo' src='"
+ logo
+ "' width=\"169\" "
+ "height=\"49\" /></td>\n  </tr>\n  <tr>\n    <td align=\"center\">"
+ "<img alt='' src=\""
+ line
+ "\" width=\"558\" height=\"18\" /></td>\n  "
+ "</tr>\n  <tr>\n    <td height=\"50\" align=\"center\" "
+ "style=\"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; "
+ "font-weight:bold; color:#000;\">Hi" + receiverFirstName
+ "! " + "</td>\n  </tr>"
+"<tr>\n<td height=\"40\" align=\"center\"  "
+"style=\"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; "
+"font-size:13px; color:#858484; text-decoration:none;\">"
+"If this does not work, paste this link into your browser."
+"</td>\n  </tr>\n  <tr>\n    <td height=\"20\" align=\"center\"  "
+"style=\"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:9px; "
+"color:#858484; text-decoration:none;\">"
+"<a href=\"" + dynamicLink
+"\" style=\"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; "
+"color:#858484; text-decoration:none;\">" + dynamicLink
+"</a> </td>\n</tr>\n"
+" <tr>\n    <td height=\"60\" align=\"center\">\n"
+"<a href=\"#\"><img alt='facebook' src=\""+facebookImage+"\" width=\"25\" height=\"25\" /></a> \n"
+"<a href=\"#\"><img alt='pintrest' src=\""+pintrestImage+"\" width=\"25\" height=\"25\" /></a>\n"
+"<a href=\"#\"><img alt='twitter' src=\""+twitterImage+"\" width=\"25\" height=\"25\" /></a>\n"
+"</td>\n  </tr>\n  <tr>\n    <td height=\"0\" align=\"center\" "
+"style=\"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; "
+"color:#858484; text-decoration:none;\">\u00a9 2013 MapNSav | "
+"All Rights Reserved<br />\n      <a href=\""+termsAndConditionsLink+"\" "
+"style=\"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; "
+"color:#858484; text-decoration:none;\">Privacy Policy</a> | "
+"<a href=\""+termsAndConditionsLink+"\" style=\"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; "
+"font-size:11px; color:#858484; text-decoration:none;\">"
+"Terms and Conditions</a></td>\n  </tr>";
```

I could not figure out the reason, expect any link to a good tutorial or suggestions.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check the raw mail that you are sending, not what you see in the GMail box... Then you should be able to spot why the output is broken.

Comment: SOrry, I forgot to mention. This issue is with IPAD, IPhone like devices only. Not in desktop or laptop.

Comment: If there's a difference between hardcoding the link VS dynamically inserting it, then certainly what you insert is malformed, and different mail agents react to that differently. So check in the raw output what your are inserting.

Comment: In raw out put it is something like this:
http: //mapnsav-dev.in/displayOffers?businessId=fR4@X0mDGLE$oQrDIxZtTR4e3Ty4rFCSoA$$


It is a link given for...., "if above link not work copy and paste it in browser"